# serve webpack bundle in express?

Tags: express, webpack

I am trying to introduce myself in webpack, this is my config server.js file:

```
const app = webpack({
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: ['whatwg-fetch', path.resolve(__dirname, 'js', 'app.js')],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'babel-loader',
           test: /\.js$/,
      },  
      {
           test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      minimize: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    debug: true
  })
  ]
});
```

I want to serve the files to express, this is the code:

```
 // Serve static resources
    app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.listen(APP_PORT, () => {
      console.log(`App is now running on http://localhost:${APP_PORT}`);
    });
```

but I had an error app.use is not a function. Help?

Comment: Where is the rest of your Express application?

Comment: it's all that what i'm trying to do @robertklep

Comment: Take a look at the Express [_"Hello World"_](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) example on how to create `app`.